# TYPO3 main-function of extension not called

Tags: typo3

On my local testserver with T3 4.5.6 the extension works without any problems but on the productionserver the main function will not be called anymore after I upgraded from 4.2 to 4.5.6.

Any hints?

Comment: what do you mean with main-function? Mainfunction of any extension oder of the exention manager itselfs?

Comment: Can you post the typoscript part where your plugin is initialized? Should be something like: plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1 = USER

Comment: No I mean the main-function from this single extension - everything else works.

Comment: you can also check it with the template analyzer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css_styled_content was installed in the Extension-Directory and came also with the 4.5 update. Deleting the installation in typo3con/ext/ solved the weird problem.

Comment: Good to know. I hope I remember when this occurs to someone else.

Comment: Yeah, glad if this helps someone. If you found the answer useful please vote for.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure the extension is installed in the Extension Manager on you production server?

You can also check this by editing the file typo3conf/localconf.php (on the prod. server) and see if your extension is listed there under `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList']` and/or `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList_FE']`. (Always check the latest entry, there could be more.)

Comment: It is installed, I checked it twice, reinstalled it - nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the function main() in your extension class.
Can you try to print some debug output to the frontend by adding `t3lib_div::debug()` inside the function?:

```
class tx_myextesnion_pi1 extends tslib_pibase {

    function main($content,$conf)   {
        t3lib_div::debug($conf);
        t3lib_div::debug("Lorem Ipsum...");
        [ your standard php code continues here... ]

    }
```

Are you sure no fatal php or mysql errors occur?
(try `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '1'` in localconf.php).

Did you also include your extensions typoscript configuration?

It's hard to guess, because main() is the standard function that is always called for a frontend plugin within an extension. So from here, we can only make educated guesses. You should try to investigate how far the processing of your extension actually goes, i.e. where it exactly stops. Then share it here.

Comment: Hi, thats how I figured out that main is not called - the first t3lib_div::debug in your sample will not be not called in my case...
First I thought debug-output is turned off, but it's not. Another weird thing is that a function wich is in exact the same file as the main function can be called (and is called) by TS.

Comment: I rechecked it again,  
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['sqlDebug'] = 1;  
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '-1';  
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['debug'] = 1;  
is turned on.

Comment: Are you calling main() by a typoscript userFunc object or from a content element (i.e. frontend plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your php error log also . It might help you to figure out the problem .Also try to add this plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1 = USER_INT then check